# найти сумму списка

Tags: python, list, список, синтаксис

если как минимум двое из них придумали и уверены в решении, в противном случае ребята не будут писать решение этой задачи.
Входные данные

В первой строке входных данных записано единственное целое число n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000) — количество задач на соревновании. Далее в n строках записано по три целых числа, каждое из которых равно 0 или 1. Если первое число в строке равно 1, то Петя уверен в решении этой задачи, в противном случае он не уверен в решении. Второе число обозначает мнение Васи, а третье — мнение Тони. Числа в строках разделены пробелами.
Выходные данные

Выведите единственное целое число — количество задач, которые друзья будут реализовывать на соревновании.

НЕ ПОЛУЧАЕТСЯ НАЙТИ СУММУ КАЖДОЙ СТРОКИ В СПИСКАХ, НАПИСАЛ ТОЛЬКО ЭТО:

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map((int, input().split()))

b = sum(a) -----здесь подчеркивает как ошибку..
if b > 2:
    count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: `b = sum(a)` как-то выпало из цикла. И `if` тоже.

Comment: Не хватает скобки

Comment: @Эникейщик Наоборот - лишняя )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
n = int(input())
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map((int, input().split()))
                ^^ тут лишняя скобка! оставить одну скобку
    b = sum(a) 
    if b > 2:
         ^^ тут нужно >= 2 либо > 1 иначе сработает только если b = 3
        count+=1
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ этот блок строк сдвинут мной вправо на 4 позиции

print(count)
```

Comment: b = sum(a) все равно подчеркивается как ошибка, что делать? не понимаю почему

Comment: @popovpetrrr Двойную скобку тут убрали `map((int`? Вот так должно быть `map(int`

Comment: да, убрал                                                 n = int(input())
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    a = list(map(int, input().split())
    b = sum(a) 
    if b >= 2:
        count+=1

print(count)

Comment: @popovpetrrr А с правого края зачем скобку убрали? Я не писал, что справа надо что-то убирать. У вас проблемы из-за того, что скобки не парные, если вы убираете две скобки - и справа и слева - эта проблема никак не может решиться. Нужно убрать одну скобку ровно в том месте, где я показал.

Comment: Ай, не заметил, извиняюсь, спасибо